# How to make nav recognize the title of a template

Tags: python, markdown, documentation, mkdocs, mkdocs-macros

If nav is not set in mkdocs.yml, navigation is created automatically. The string is determined by the following priority

1. the title of each page (h1 string starting with #)
2. the file name

I would like to display the h1 string in the navigation even if the template contains it, but it does not work. I use **mkdocs-macros-plugin** as a template.
Any suggestions on what to do?

---

Reproduction example

```
[packages]
mkdocs = "==1.1"
mkdocs-macros-plugin = "==0.7.0"
```

```
docs/
└── index.md
templates/
└── template.md
mkdocs.yml
```

mkdocs.yml

```
plugins:
  - search
  - macros:
      include_dir: templates
```

templates/template.md

```
# AAAA

~~~
```

docs/index.md

```
{% include "template.md" %}
```

---

The navigation obtained in this setup is

```
index
```

I want the following navigation.

```
AAAA
```

Answer (score 0):

I am the author of mkdocs-macros. This is an issue that is not as simple as it seems. First of all, I suggest that you update to the latest version of mkdocs (>=1.5) and mkdocs-macros (>=1.1), to see if there is there is any difference in behavior.

Then, if there is no improvement, I suggest you to open an issue on [github's repository for mkdocs-macros](https://github.com/fralau/mkdocs_macros_plugin/issues), to see what could be done about it.